# how to stop servlet?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, jakarta-ee

I have a servlet that looks like this:

```
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException{
    String param1 = request.getParameter("param1");
    String param2 = request.getParameter("param2");

    validateInput(param1, param2, request, response);

    //if nothing's wrong with the input, do this and that
}


private void validateInput(String param1, String param2, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException{
    boolean fail = false;

    //validate input blah blah blah

    if (fail){
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.write("invalid input");
        //end process or servlet
    }
}
```

The idea is that I want to pass `param1` and `param2` to function `validateInput()` to validate whether or not the input is valid. If input is invalid, write a message back and then end the process. My question is **how to end the process?** I'm aware of that calling `return;` in `doPost()` will end the process but I'm trying to avoid returning any value from `validateInput()` to `doPost()` just for the sake of ending the process. I personally feel that it's more readable this way rather than returning `true` or `false` to `doPost()` and call `return;` there. Is there a way to do it? Or is it simply impossible?

Comment: Returning a boolean is exactly what you should do. you should just return !fail and let doPost handle the writing and terminating.

Comment: @dtech: if there's no way to end the request in `validateInput()`, then yeah.. that's the only way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Control will always return to `doPost` after `validateInput` runs unless you throw an exception (either an unchecked exception or `IOException` in this case).

So if you do not return ANY value from `validateInput` to `doPost`, even if you commit the response, `doPost` will still go on to do whatever it is supposed to do. (Of course, if the response is commited, the browser will be entirely unaware of any further activity on the server side).

You will need to return a value, throw an exception (which `doPost` may catch) *or* set a global value that `doPost` checks (which is just messy).

Comment: in other word, do u mean that there's no way to stop that single request without throwing exception (which is not preferable here) or returning any value from `validateInput()`? I really don't want to return any value just for the sake of ending the request. I want to make it clean. :(

Comment: Yes, that is what I'm saying. And there is nothing "unclean" about a validation method returning a true/false value. That is the output of its function.

Answer (score 9):

```
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException{
    String param1 = request.getParameter("param1");
    String param2 = request.getParameter("param2");

    if(!isValidInput(param1, param2)){
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.write("invalid input");
        return;
    }

    //if nothing's wrong with the input, do this and that

}


private boolean isValidInput(String param1, String param2){
    boolean fail = false;
    //validate input and return true/false

}
```

Answer (score 1):

More sophisticated way would be .

- validate and setAttributes to request if error found and *forward* request to jsp
- on jsp check for the error attribute if any present display them

---

**See Also**

- [our Servlet wiki page, it explains it very well with example](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info)

Comment: I'm not working with JSP. I use simple HTML and JavaScript to request.

Comment: get message via ajax and display it

Answer (score 1):

What are you calling "the process"?  That single request?  If yes, then sending a message back DOES end the servlet's responsibility.  HTTP is a request/response protocol.

If you mean stopping the servlet, that's not right.  The servlet runs in the container, which is still going.  It waits for the next request.

I don't see anything that merits stopping.  Validation and routing back with errors is common.

Comment: Yep, I refer to that single request. What I want is just to validate the input. If fail, write some messages using that `out.write()` and end that single request. By only calling `out.write()`, the request doesn't stop there. It will continue with the rest of the code if any.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

I changed your validate to return a boolean, so you can run an if statement on it in the doPost method. I also made it return a success instead of failure, just so the check makes more sense once you've returned.

response.sendError will allow you to do a generic error page (See this: http://blogs.atlassian.com/2007/07/responsesenderror_vs_responses/) instead of your output. If you want that you'll want setStatus (again, see the link).

The return should terminate execution and prevent the rest from happening, but it won't shut down the servlet like a system.exit(0) would.

```
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException{
    String param1 = request.getParameter("param1");
    String param2 = request.getParameter("param2");

    if (! validateInput(param1, param2, request, response)){
        response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        //Or you can use this instead... 
        //response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        //PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        //out.write("invalid input");
        return;
    }
    //if nothing's wrong with the input, do this and that
}




private boolean validateInput(String param1, String param2, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException{
    boolean success = false;

    //validate input blah blah blah

    return success;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to get a reference to the `OutputStream` to write HTML back to the client?

You can make use of `response.getOutputStream()` that would return a `ServletOutputStream`.

Once you have written to this stream, you need to finish. You will have to `close()` and `flush()` once you are done.

Whatever you write to this stream will be sent to the browser. Also remember to call the 
`response.setContentType("text/html");` so the browser knows its dealing with HTML.

Answer (score -1):

have you tried with either one of the following

`response.sendRedirect("some view.jsp");`

(or)

`System.exit(0); // which exits from the program`

Comment: `System.exit(0)` will end the JVM, not only that single request. And i can't use `sendRedirect()` because I"m not working with .jsp here. I'm working with html and javascript.